# Include template fields in export language

Tags: multilingual, language-fallback

When trying to use the Export Languages tool in the control panel I would like to know if I can include template fields in the export. When using this tool to export pages for language translation it does not include template specific fields to the template such as the "Featured Text".

Is there some adjustment I need to make in the Template Section or Template Field item to make sure it is included in the Export Language XML file? In case it makes a difference I am currently using Sitecore 8.1.

Comment: Is it not exporting for any of the languages? Any specific field types are not being exported?

Comment: Always seem to miss the obvious. figured it out based on your comment, I will put it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AmitabhVyas for helping me realize this.

My issue was with fallback values. Apparently Sitecore does not export language fields when they are fallback values. Found out that the fields properly export when the field is not set as a fallback value.

Specifically in my case Japanese was set to fallback to EN while Chinese had been translated. So English and Chinese would export the field but Japanese would not as it was the English fallback.